# Why auth('api')->user() return me null if I use in api.php but if I use it in web.php it is working

Tags: php, backend, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7, having this code in *api.php*

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->get('/booking','APIController@testauth');

public function testauth() {
    $userInfo=auth('api')->user();
}
```

If I use that, it redirect me to homepage, and if I don't use middleware, it returns me null.
Nevertheless if I use it on *web.php* it returns me the user.

Where is this difference coming from?

Comment: Get the user from the api guard directly: `auth()->guard('api')->user()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For API please use Auth Facade to get user

```
Auth::user()
```

Comment: It returns me null as well,
$userInfo=Auth::user();
        dd($userInfo);
obviously I am authenticated

Comment: what sort of auth are you using. Are you using passport?

Comment: I installed it php artisan laravel/ui

Comment: I just installed it with the laravel/ui and the authentication was done :D

Comment: nop, it is the same problem, if I call it from web.php it is working, but it is not working from api.php, I don't know why :S

Comment: laravel/ui doesnt solve your auth problems as it just installs the views..go look at JWT or Passport or default laravel api guard

Comment: you must set this up for the api part of your project to work

Comment: @CarlosIvan i could be more helpful to you in chat

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know it, I am going to research how to do it